# UIElement.Projection only in Silverlight and not in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight

I downloaded a sample code from here:
http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/ShowHideWithFlip

Now my problem is that i'm using WPF and the guy is using Silverlight..

I thought they are both using .NET 4 but i found out there is ".NET 4" and there is ".NET for Silverlight" totla diffrent things..

i get this error:

```
'System.Windows.UIElement' does not contain a definition for 'Projection' and no   extension method 'Projection' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.UIElement' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I just found out why, the guy is using .NET for Silverlight and i'm using .NET 4.

Silverlight:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement(v=VS.95).aspx

.NET 4: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.aspx

There is a solution for this?

I thought WPF and Silverlight is kinde of the same ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921107(v=pandp.20).aspx )

I just found this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/9acb712a-b592-49e7-83a1-e3ee7ff03014

This is my problam but i cant figure how to use the ViewPort3D.
here is the part of the code:

```
        if (showElement.Projection == null)
        {
            showElement.Projection = new PlaneProjection();
            showElement.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(.5, .5);
        }

        if (hideElement.Projection == null)
        {
            hideElement.Projection = new PlaneProjection();
            hideElement.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(.5, .5);
        }

        mainStoryboard = new Storyboard();

        BackEase hide_ease = new BackEase() { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut, Amplitude = 0.2 };

        // Show           
        PlaneProjection showPP = new PlaneProjection();
        CompositeTransform showCT = new CompositeTransform();
```

Comment: In WPF you don't need a `Projection` property because you can just texture map onto a 3-D plane. Since Silverlight doesn't have 3-D, they added the `Projection` just to make that one feature possible.

Comment: So you know can i do a flip effect like in that example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this doesn't exist in WPF 3.5 or 4, no.  Only in Silverlight.  However, you can certainly roll your own 3-D in WPF.  Here's [one example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ContentControl3D.aspx) of 3-D rotated controls.  Here's Microsoft's doc on [Viewport3D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewport3d.aspx).

Comment: Do you know can i do a flip effect like in that example?

Comment: Here's a Xaml-only solution for flipping list items: http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/05/17/wpf-flippable-3D-list