# Tilt / skew element vertically to look like a trapezoid

Tags: wpf, xaml, 3d

How can I tilt a UI element vertically.
For example, I want to show a rectangle tilted vertically at a 45 degree angle like a [trapezoid](http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=trapezoid&qpvt=trapizoid&qpvt=trapizoid&FORM=IGRE#view=detail&id=8B0AFCD3B8E0E25ED3558456ED67E3232456CC08&selectedIndex=0).

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730114/transform-rectangular-image-into-trapezoid

Comment: Related: [http://stackoverflow.com/q/6752731/1136211](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6752731/1136211), especially the first comment on the question.

Comment: Also WPF 3D as in : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237824/c-wpf-image-transformation-over-a-trapezoid

Comment: @Bizz MatrixTransform can't do that. You would have to use WPF 3D.

Comment: @Clemens oops my mistake!

Comment: I am stuck. I really need to figure out something that should be basic. I've found this: http://jobijoy.blogspot.com/2009/04/3d-flipper-control-using-silverlight-30.html However, as mentioned, it's only in Silverlight.